# ¿Cómo hacer transparente un label en WinForms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera saber como puedo manejar la transparencia de un label en *Windows Forms* en C#, quisera hacer un efecto de desvanecimiento a un label.

Comment: Hola @soundboy809 por favor revisa las respuestas que te han dado ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estuve investigando un poco y en MSDN indican que solo el `BackColor` es posible hacer transparente seteando el *Alpha* utilizando `Color.FromArgb()`, te paso un ejemplo:

```
     label1.BackColor  = Color.FromArgb(i, Color.Blue);
     label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(i, Color.Red);   //No se ve afectada la opacidad.
```

Donde `i` lo pudes ir seteando en cada `Tick` de un `Timer`

Si Intentas esto,  `label1.ForeColor` no se ve afectado por el `alpha` del `ARGB`. [Ver Aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/ab564345-dcc8-4c85-b56c-ff6d3097d905/label-opacity)

**EDITADO**

Aquí tienes otra forma de hacerlo, agrega una clase en blanco a tu proyecto, pega el código siguiente, y al cambiarle el texto vas a ver el efecto. Para agregarlo a tu formulario puedes buscar el control desde el `toolbox` en tiempo de diseño.

> Extraído del post de: **nobugz** en MSDN. [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ded003e3-ab35-4c23-b645-af7f82df57f0/fade-the-text-in-a-label?forum=winforms)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FadeLabel : Label {
  private ColorAnimator mAnim = new ColorAnimator();
  private string mText = "";

  public FadeLabel() {
    mAnim.Change += new EventHandler(mAnim_Change);
  }
  public override Color ForeColor {
    get { return base.ForeColor; }
    set { base.ForeColor = value; mAnim.Color = value; }
  }
  public override string Text {
    get { return base.Text; }
    set { if (base.Text != "") mAnim.Begin(); mText = base.Text; base.Text = value; }
  }
  void mAnim_Change(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Invalidate();
  }
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    string txt = mAnim.Fading ? mText : base.Text;
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(mAnim.Color))
      e.Graphics.DrawString(txt, this.Font, br, this.ClientRectangle);
  }

  internal class ColorAnimator : Timer {
    public event EventHandler Change;
    private const int cRate = 5;    // Tweak this
    private Color mColor;
    private int mValue = 255;
    private int mStep = -1;

    public Color Color {
      get { return Color.FromArgb(mValue, mColor); }
      set { mColor = value; }
    }
    public void Begin() {
      mValue = 255;
      mStep = -cRate;
      Interval = 16;
      Enabled = true;
    }
    public bool Fading {
      get { return Enabled && mStep < 0; }
    }
    protected override void OnTick(EventArgs e) {
      mValue += mStep;
      if (mValue <= 0) { mValue = 0; mStep = -mStep; }
      if (mValue >= 255) { mValue = 255; Enabled = false; }
      if (Change != null) Change(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```

Aquí puedes ver el control:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @soundboy809 acabo de editar mi respuesta, lo que agrego lo acabo  de probar y funciona. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 4):

Para un `label` sobre un `Winform`

```
myLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

o usando `FromArgb()`

```
myLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(120, Color.Blue);
```

*120 es el `alpha` de 0 a 255

más información (inglés):

- [Label Opacity.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/ab564345-dcc8-4c85-b56c-ff6d3097d905/label-opacity)
- [Como hacer un label sin color.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639482/how-to-do-a-background-for-a-label-will-be-without-color)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent`

Y para el fade :

```
For FadeIn = 0.0 To 1.1 Step 0.1
  Label1.forecolor = Color.FromArgb(FadeIn, 200, 200, 200);
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Next

For FadeOut = 90 To 10 Step -10
   Label1.forecolor = Color.FromArgb(FadeOut, 200, 200, 200);
   Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
Next
```

Comment: con eso solo pones el fondo transparente, y es las letras que quiero hacer especie de un fade in o fade out

Comment: Gracias por la observacion